# Cannot find any information on property in Java JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, javabeans

In my Jsp page, I am getting the error :

> Cannot find any information on property 'productList' in a bean of
>   type 'Smithd81.InventoryManager'

The InventoryManager class has a getProductList() method which returns a List of Product objects, which I need to access.

In my JSP:

```
<jsp:useBean id = "productManager" scope = "page"  class = "Smithd81.InventoryManager" />
<jsp:getProperty name = "productManager" property = "productList" />
```

I thought I had this correct on the getProperty property name- starts in lower case and whatnot, which  is the typical pitfall for this error, but I definitely have it spelled correctly.

Where I seem to get the error:

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${productManager.productList}">
                    <div>
                        <form action="inventory" method="POST">
                            <label>
                                <span>UPC</span>
                                <input type="text" name="upc" value="${p.getUpc()}" readonly="readonly"/>
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Short Details</span>
                                <input type="text" name="shortDetails" value="${p.getShortDetails()}" />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Long Details</span>
                                <input type="text" name="longDetails" value="${p.getLongDetails()}" />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Price</span>
                                <input type="text" name="price" value="${p.getPrice()}" />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>Stock</span>
                                <input type="text" name="stock" value="${p.getStock()}" />
                            </label>
                            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Edit" />
                            <input type="submit" name="button" value="Delete" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
```

For clarification, Inside the InventoryManager Class, the method signature reads:

```
public static List getProductList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            List<Product> productsList = new ArrayList<>(); //empty product list
            Collection<Product> productsFromFile = CollectionFileStorageUtility.load(Product.class);//loads collection from file
            productsList.addAll(productsFromFile);// adds all current products from file to the productList List.
            return productsList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException: error accessing data file.");
            return null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ClassNotFoundException: error accessing class.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor your package name to lowercase. Another case is that you are trying to call static method on object (your bean finally is object). So method `getProductList()` should be non-static.

Comment: when I go to do this, it says package name smithd81 already exists; where do i check for this?

Comment: Nevermind, I found a workaround to rename it. However, I still get the original error

Comment: I've just seen that you are trying to call static method on object (your bean finally is object). So method `getProductList()` should be non-static.

Comment: please post your last comment as a full response so I can accept the answer.